# MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''?

Tags: mysql

When upload the sql to phpmyadmin after edit a 1000+ lien and the

MySQL said:
Documentation#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1489

Static analysis:
1 errors were found during analysis.
8 values were expected, but found 4. (near "(" at position 114466)

```
INSERT INTO `cities` (`id`, `name`, `state_id`, `cost`, `status`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `deleted_at`) VALUES
(1, 'Adrar', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:05:34', '2022-02-08 03:05:34', NULL),
(2, 'Akabli', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:06:01', '2022-02-08 03:06:01', NULL),
(3, 'Aougrout', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:06:18', '2022-02-08 03:06:18', NULL),
(4, 'Aoulef', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:06:36', '2022-02-08 03:06:36', NULL),
(5, 'Bouda', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:06:58', '2022-02-08 03:06:58', NULL),
(6, 'Charouine', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:07:07', '2022-02-08 03:07:07', NULL),
(7, 'Deldoul', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:07:12', '2022-02-08 03:07:12', NULL),
(8, 'Fenoughil', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:07:19', '2022-02-08 03:07:19', NULL),
(9, 'In Zghmir', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:07:23', '2022-02-08 03:07:23', NULL),
(10, 'Ksar Kaddour', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:07:30', '2022-02-08 03:07:30', NULL),
(11, 'Metarfa', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:07:35', '2022-02-08 03:07:35', NULL),
(12, 'Ouled Ahmed Tammi', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:07:40', '2022-02-08 03:07:40', NULL),
(13, 'Ouled Aïssa', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:07:47', '2022-02-08 03:07:47', NULL),
(14, 'Ouled Saïd', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:07:55', '2022-02-08 03:07:55', NULL),
(15, 'Reggane', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:08:02', '2022-02-08 03:08:02', NULL),
(16, 'Sali', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:08:26', '2022-02-08 03:08:26', NULL),
(17, 'Sebaa', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:08:36', '2022-02-08 03:08:36', NULL),
(18, 'Talmine', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:08:41', '2022-02-08 03:08:41', NULL),
(19, 'Tamantit', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:08:48', '2022-02-08 03:08:48', NULL),
(20, 'Tamekten', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:08:54', '2022-02-08 03:08:54', NULL),
(21, 'Tamest', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:09:02', '2022-02-08 03:09:02', NULL),
(22, 'Timimoun', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:09:08', '2022-02-08 03:09:08', NULL),
(23, 'Tinerkouk', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:09:13', '2022-02-08 03:09:13', NULL),
(24, 'Tit', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:09:18', '2022-02-08 03:09:18', NULL),
(25, 'Tsabit', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:09:24', '2022-02-08 03:09:24', NULL),
(26, 'Zaouiet Kounta', 1, 1400.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:09:30', '2022-02-08 03:09:30', NULL),
(27, 'Abou El Hassan', 2, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:10:04', '2022-02-08 03:10:04', NULL),
(28, 'Bénairia', 2, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:12:00', '2022-02-08 03:12:00', NULL),
(29, 'Beni Bouateb', 2, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:12:08', '2022-02-08 03:12:08', NULL),
(30, 'Beni Haoua', 2, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:12:14', '2022-02-08 03:12:14', NULL),
(31, 'Beni Rached', 2, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:12:23', '2022-02-08 03:12:23', NULL),
(32, 'Boukadir', 2, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:12:34', '2022-02-08 03:12:34', NULL),
(33, 'Bouzeghaia', 2, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:12:52', '2022-02-08 03:12:52', NULL),
```

```
(1432, 'Tamzoura', 46, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1433, 'Terga', 46, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1434, 'Berriane', 47, 1050.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1435, 'Bounoura', 47, 1050.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1436, 'Dhayet Bendhahoua', 47, 1050.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1437, 'El Atteuf', 47, 1050.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1438, 'El Guerrara', 47, 1050.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1439, 'El Menia', 47, 1050.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1440, 'Ghardaïa', 47, 1050.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1441, 'Hassi Fehal', 47, 1050.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1442, 'Hassi Gara', 47, 1050.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1443, 'Mansoura', 47, 1050.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1444, 'Metlili', 47, 1050.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1445, 'Sebseb', 47, 1050.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1446, 'Zelfana', 47, 1050.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1447, 'Aïn Rahma', 48, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1448, 'Aïn Tarek', 48, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1449, 'Ammi Moussa', 48, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1450, 'Belassel Bouzegza', 48, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1451, 'Bendaoud', 48, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1452, 'Beni Dergoun', 48, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1453, 'Beni Zentis', 48, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1454, 'Dar Ben Abdellah', 48, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
```

```
(1479, 'Sidi M Hamed Ben Ali', 48, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1480, 'Sidi M Hamed Benaouda', 48, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1481, 'Sidi Saada', 48, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1482, 'Souk El Had', 48, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1483, 'Yellel', 48, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),
(1484, 'Zemmora', 48, 900.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `cities`
--
ALTER TABLE `cities`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `cities`
--
ALTER TABLE `cities`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=43;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: The message is telling you exactly where the error is. I have no way to know whether you've posted line 1489 here (and I'm not going to count)

Comment: This is the line :

(1444, 'Metlili', 47, 1050.00, 1, '2022-02-08 03:14:07', '2022-02-08 03:14:07', NULL),

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**

THE ERROR IS

```
(1311, 'Gouraya', ( 750.00, 1,
```

"("